# php - create function name with variable

Tags: php, foreach

I have some code like this

```
$form_names = GFFormsModel::get_forms();
foreach ($form_names as $form) {
  add_action("gform_pre_submission_".$form->id, "format_ecp_event_meta_from_gravity");

  function format_ecp_event_meta_from_gravity(){

  }
}
```

Since i'm using foreach loop **functions get duplicated**. So is there a way to make the function unique using `$form->id` ?

I mean i want the function names like this

```
function format_ecp_event_meta_from_gravity_{$form->id}(){

}
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Looks like the perfect use case scenario for an anonymous function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: can you explane what you want to do with this functions i think it's not good to create functions on loop

Comment: @Niko But my function has very large code. CAn you explain how to use large code in anonymous function?

Comment: @Giri It's just the same as with normal functions. Just the first line is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use closures:

```
$form_names = GFFormsModel::get_forms();
foreach ($form_names as $form) {
    $func = function() {
        ...
    };
    add_action("gform_pre_submission_".$form->id, $func);
}
```

Comment: The functions probably also need to be passed into `add_action()` because they seem to get invoked there.

Comment: @hek2mgl Could you explain this last line `$functions ['func_name']= $func;` ? what name should i replace with func_name?

Comment: @Giri Note that your question is really vague because I don't know what `add_action` does. (You missed to describe that properly in your question). But without knowing more I would suggest to simply drop that last line. check my update

Comment: [add_action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) is a wordpress hook. Hey is it possible to change `$func` variable to `${'func_'.$form->id}` ?

Comment: @Giri You should give this a try! Wordpress probably uses `call_user_func_array` to invoke the function and that should also work with a closure.